# Update table from same table

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a data set in which I would like to update a column `PREVACCEPTID`.

The update is based on the contents of the same table, a sample data is shown below:

[image: BEFORE]

The column should be updated after a search to see if station has had previous acceptances and what was this?

If we SELECT all DISTINCT 'ACCEPTID' for station A we would get the below.

[image: DISTINCT ACCEPT IDS]

I want to use this DISTINCT ACCEPTID to populate 'PREVACCEPTID'.

So whereever I have an entry with for e.g. '142692', I would lookup the sub-table and check if there are exists any previous ACCEPTID s, if that is the case populate with the previous one, in this case '142691' (see after results table as they are populated)

I have tried a few things now, I am getting an error for the below:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.PREVACCEPTID = (CASE 
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT b.ACCEPTID) = 1
                            THEN b.ACCEPTID
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT b.ACCEPTID) > 1 
                              AND b.ACCEPTID <> MIN(a.ACCEPTID) 
                            THEN b.ACCEPTID - 1
                      END)
FROM dbo.table a 
RIGHT JOIN dbo.table b ON b.STATION = a.STATION
                       AND b.PERIOD = a.PERIOD
                       AND b.ACCEPTID = a.ACCEPTID
```

I get this error:

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 326
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

The end result is per below:

[image: AFTER]

I think a cte would be better option, but i have never used one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sure looks like SQL Server...so why did you tag with MySQL?

Comment: Also, showing us the final output after the update would be helpful.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are correct this is SQLserver, been bashing my head trying to figure this out for a while.  Tried a few things and rushed posting this.  It seems the accept IDs are generated in increments therefore the previous accept ID would be -1.  But I hoping to use the time to identify the accept ID using the timestamp.

Comment: Rules are not clear to me.

Comment: @paparazzo which part?  I want to populate 'PREVACCEPTID' with an 'ACCEPTID'  the 'PREVACCEPTID' is the same as 'ACCEPTID' if there are no previous accept ID for that particular station.  a station could have 1 to x accept IDs.  In this case there are 3 (142691, 142692 and 142693)  so the prev accept ID for 142692 is 142691. I want to go through the dataset and populate accordingly.

Comment: Still not clear to me and update the question.  You mention time order.  You don't define previous.  You only show update of 3.  VTC

Comment: @paparazzo per request have updated the question.  The accept IDs get populated chronologically. so using the time could search if a station has had previous acceptances, if so what was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question and subsequent comments correctly, I assume you want the previous AcceptID to be populated to be last AcceptID for a given set of rows sharing the same Station and Period. Last I assume would be defined by the time components (StackDate and QTime). And, in the case where there is only one row for a given Station and Period, you'd want the Previous AcceptID to be set to be the same as AcceptID for that row.

Under the above conditions, below is a query that will work. *Note: Replace table 'Test' with your own table name.*

```
UPDATE t SET PrevAcceptID = 
  ISNULL(
      (SELECT TOP 1 AcceptID 
       FROM Test t2 
       WHERE t2.Station = t.Station AND t2.Period = t.Period AND t2.AcceptID < t.AcceptID ORDER BY StackDate DESC, QTime DESC), 
         AcceptID)
FROM Test AS t
```

Comment: thank you for this, it's getting towards what I want to achieve.  here we are selecting the 'LAST' acceptid but i want to be able to select the previous.  So this will give me '142691' for the whole list after changing your code to sort 'ASC'  But what i want is to retrieve '142692' for '142693' entry and '142691' for '142692' i.e. the 'previous' accepID and not the LAST.

Comment: ok, i have managed to do it, using a variation of your answer, thanks for steering in the right direction.